# Conditional Replace in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace values in a pandas dataframe based on a condition in another column. I tried these approaches:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({"Column1":["A", "B", "ABC", "D", "AB"], "Column2":["H", "I", "H", "I", "L"]})
mydf[mydf["Column2"]=="I"]["Column1"].replace("B", "A", inplace=True)
mydf.loc[mydf['Column2']=="I", 'Column1'].replace("B", "A", inplace=True)
```

The replace operation seams to work. But it is not replaced in the original mydf. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: DO not chain the replace inplace with .,loc

Comment: I don't know how I could do it without.
This approach would work, but it doesn't look very clean: 
`mydf.loc[mydf['Column2']=="I", 'Column1'] = mydf.loc[mydf['Column2']=="I", 'Column1'].replace("B", "A")`